# How to generate group in jsplumb angular and add nodes to it dynamically after the group is created in angular 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, jsplumb

I would like to create a jsplumb group and then add nodes to it dynamically. But I can find in the document that one node needs to created and then after that only it can be added to the group. But in my case I have to add the group first and then I will drag drop the node. Both should have same jsplumb instance so that I can save the node values as well as group values.

I got this code from the main documentation.

HTML

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>jsPlumb - groups demonstration</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/jsplumbtoolkit-defaults.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/jsplumbtoolkit-demo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css">

</head>

    <body data-demo-id="groups">

        <a style="margin:10px 0 0 10px;display:inline-block" href="https://jsplumbtoolkit.com"><img src="../../img/logo-jsplumb-green.png"></a>

        <div class="jtk-demo-main">
            <!-- demo -->
            <div class="jtk-demo-canvas canvas-wide flowchart-demo jtk-surface jtk-surface-nopan" id="canvas">

                <div class="group-container" id="container1" group="one">
                    <div class="title"></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Elements constrained to group (<strong>constrain:true</strong>)</li>
                        <li>Elements are draggable to other groups </li>
                        <li>Deletes group and children</li>
                        <li>Not droppable (<strong>droppable:false</strong>)</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="del" delete-all></div>
                    <div class="node-collapse"></div>
                    <div id="c1_1" class="w" style="left:30px;top:35px">1.1</div>
                    <div id="c1_2" class="w" style="left:160px;top:140px">1.2</div>
                </div>

                <div class="group-container" id="container2" group="two">
                    <div class="title"></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Elements are reverted on drop outside (<strong>revert:true</strong>)</li>
                        <li>Elements not draggable to other groups (<strong>dropOverride:true</strong>)</li>
                        <li>Deletes group only</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="del"></div>
                    <div class="node-collapse"></div>
                    <div id="c2_1" class="w" style="left:30px;top:40px">2.1</div>
                    <div id="c2_2" class="w" style="left:150px;top:160px">2.2</div>
                </div>

                <div class="group-container" id="container3" group="three">
                    <div class="title"></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Elements may be dragged outside bounds (<strong>revert:false</strong>)</li>
                        <li>Elements are draggable to other groups</li>
                        <li>Deletes group only</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="del"></div>
                    <div class="node-collapse"></div>
                    <div id="c3_1" class="w" style="left:30px;top:35px">3.1</div>
                    <div id="c3_2" class="w" style="left:80px;top:162px">3.2</div>
                </div>

                <div class="group-container" id="container4" group="four">
                    <div class="title"></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Elements pruned on drop outside (<strong>prune:true</strong>)</li>
                        <li>Elements are draggable to other groups</li>
                        <li>Deletes group and children</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="del" delete-all></div>
                    <div class="node-collapse"></div>
                    <div id="c4_1" class="w" style="left:30px;top:35px">4.1</div>
                    <div id="c4_2" class="w" style="left:110px;top:150px">4.2</div>
                </div>

                <div class="group-container" id="container5" group="five">
                    <div class="title"></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Elements orphaned on drop outside (<strong>orphan:true</strong>)</li>
                        <li>Elements are draggable to other groups</li>
                        <li>Deletes group only</li>
                        <li>Not droppable (<strong>droppable:false</strong>)</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="del"></div>
                    <div class="node-collapse"></div>
                    <div id="c5_1" class="w" style="left:30px;top:35px">5.1</div>
                    <div id="c5_2" class="w" style="left:140px;top:130px">5.2</div>
                </div>

                <div class="group-container" id="container6" group="six">
                    <div class="title"></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>No connections shown when group collapsed (<strong>proxied:false</strong>)</li>
                        <li>Elements are draggable to other groups</li>
                        <li>Deletes group and children</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="del" delete-all></div>
                    <div class="node-collapse"></div>
                    <div id="c6_1" class="w" style="left:160px;top:45px">6.1</div>
                    <div id="c6_2" class="w" style="left:30px;top:150px">6.2</div>
                </div>

                <div class="group-container" id="container7" group="seven">
                    <div class="title"></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Elements are draggable to other groups, using ghost proxy (<strong>ghost:true</strong>)</li>
                        <li>Deletes group and children</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="del" delete-all></div>
                    <div class="node-collapse"></div>
                    <div id="c7_1" class="w" style="left:30px;top:35px">7.1</div>
                    <div id="c7_2" class="w" style="left:90px;top:150px">7.2</div>
                </div>
 <div class="group-container" id="jananicontainer" group="janani">
                    <div class="title"></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Elements are draggable to other groups, using ghost proxy (<strong>ghost:true</strong>)</li>
                        <li>Deletes group and children</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="del" delete-all></div>
                    <div class="node-collapse"></div>
                    <div id="jananinode1" class="w" style="left:30px;top:35px">Janani node 1</div>
                    <div id="jananinode2" class="w" style="left:90px;top:150px">Janani node 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="w" id="standalone" style="left:455px;top:280px" title="drag me into a group. if you want to.">?</div>

                <div class="events"><h3>Events</h3><div id="events"></div></div>
            </div>
            <!-- /demo -->
            <!-- explanation -->
            <div class="description">
                <h4>GROUPS</h4>
                <p>Demonstrates all of the ways you can use Groups.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- /explanation -->
        </div>


        <!-- JS -->
        <script src="../../dist/js/jsplumb.js"></script>

        <!-- groups -->
        <script src="../../src/group.js"></script>

        <script src="../demo-list.js"></script>

        <script src="demo.js"></script>


    </body>

</html>
```

js

jsPlumb.ready(function () {

```
var j = window.j = jsPlumb.getInstance({Container:canvas, Connector:"StateMachine", Endpoint:["Dot", {radius:3}], Anchor:"Center"});

j.bind("connection", function(p) {
    p.connection.bind("click", function() {
        j.detach(this);
    });
});

var evts = document.querySelector("#events");
var _appendEvent = function(name, detail) {
    evts.innerHTML = "<br/><strong>" + name + "</strong><br/> " + detail + "<br/>" + evts.innerHTML;
};
j.bind("group:addMember", function(p) {
    _appendEvent("group:addMember", p.group.id + " - " + p.el.id);
});
j.bind("group:removeMember", function(p) {
    _appendEvent("group:removeMember", p.group.id + " - " + p.el.id);
});
j.bind("group:expand", function(p) {
    _appendEvent("group:expand", p.group.id);
});
j.bind("group:collapse", function(p) {
    _appendEvent("group:collapse", p.group.id);
});
j.bind("group:add", function(p) {
    _appendEvent("group:add", p.group.id);
});
j.bind("group:remove", function(p) {
    _appendEvent("group:remove", p.group.id);
});

// connect some before configuring group
j.connect({source:c1_1, target:c2_1});
j.connect({source:c2_1, target:c3_1});
j.connect({source:c2_2, target:c6_2});
j.connect({source:c3_1, target:c4_1});
j.connect({source:c4_1, target:c5_1});
j.connect({source:c1_1,target:c1_2});
j.connect({source:c2_1,target:c2_2});

// NOTE ordering here. we make one draggable before adding it to the group, and we add the other to the group
//before making it draggable. they should both be constrained to the group extents.
j.draggable(c1_1);
j.addGroup({
    el:container1,
    id:"one",
    constrain:true,
    anchor:"Continuous",
    endpoint:"Blank",
    droppable:false
});
j.addToGroup("one", c1_1);
j.addToGroup("one", c1_2);
j.draggable(c1_2);


j.draggable(c2_1);
j.addGroup({
    el:container2,
    id:"two",
    dropOverride:true,
    endpoint:["Dot", { radius:3 }]
});  //(the default is to revert)
j.addToGroup("two", c2_1);
j.addToGroup("two", c2_2);
j.draggable(c2_2);

j.draggable(c3_1);
j.addGroup({
    el:container3,
    id:"three",
    revert:false,
    endpoint:["Dot", { radius:3 }]
});
j.addToGroup("three", c3_1);
j.addToGroup("three", c3_2);
j.draggable(c3_2);

j.draggable(c4_1);
j.addGroup({
    el:container4,
    id:"four",
    prune:true,
    endpoint:["Dot", { radius:3 }]
});
j.addToGroup("four", c4_1);
j.addToGroup("four", c4_2);
j.draggable(c4_2);

j.draggable(c5_1);
j.addGroup({
    el:container5,
    id:"five",
    orphan:true,
    droppable:false,
    endpoint:["Dot", { radius:3 }]
});
j.addToGroup("five", [c5_1, c5_2]);
j.draggable(c5_2);

j.draggable(c6_1);
j.addGroup({
    el:container6,
    id:"six",
    proxied:false,
    endpoint:["Dot", { radius:3 }]
});
j.addToGroup("six", [c6_1, c6_2]);
j.draggable(c6_2);

j.draggable(c7_1);
j.addGroup({
    el:container7,
    id:"seven",
    ghost:true,
    endpoint:["Dot", { radius:3 }]
});
j.addToGroup("seven", [c7_1, c7_2]);
j.draggable(c7_2);

// the independent element that demonstrates the fact that it can be dropped onto a group
j.draggable("standalone");
//janani test start
j.draggable(jananinode1);
  j.addGroup({
    el:jananicontainer,
    id:"janani",
    ghost:true,
    endpoint:["Dot", { radius:3 }]
});
j.addToGroup("janani", [jananinode1,jananinode2]);
j.draggable(jananinode2);
j.connect({source:"jananinode1",target:"jananinode2"});

//janani test end
//... and connect others afterwards.
j.connect({source:c3_1,target:c3_2});
j.connect({source:c4_1,target:c4_2});
j.connect({source:c5_1,target:c5_2});
j.connect({source:c5_1,target:c3_2});
j.connect({source:c5_1,target:container5, anchors:["Center", "Continuous"]});
j.connect({source:c5_2,target:c6_1});
j.connect({source:c6_2,target:c7_1});

// delete group button
j.on(canvas, "click", ".del", function() {
    var g = this.parentNode.getAttribute("group");
    j.removeGroup(g, this.getAttribute("delete-all") != null);
});

// collapse/expand group button
j.on(canvas, "click", ".node-collapse", function() {
    var g = this.parentNode.getAttribute("group"), collapsed = j.hasClass(this.parentNode, "collapsed");

    j[collapsed ? "removeClass" : "addClass"](this.parentNode, "collapsed");
    j[collapsed ? "expandGroup" : "collapseGroup"](g);
});

jsPlumb.fire("jsPlumbDemoLoaded", j);
```

});

css

```
.w {
    position:absolute;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid black;
    font-size:12px;
    border-radius:3px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:WhiteSmoke;
    opacity:0.7;
    z-index:10;
    color:black;
    cursor:move;
}

.w:hover {
    background-color:#629f8d;
}

.group-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: WhiteSmoke;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor:move;
}

.group-container ul {
    margin-left:25px;
    padding: 0;
}

.group-container ul li {
    list-style-type:circle;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.large {
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
}

.group-container.collapsed {
    height:40px;
}

.title {
    background-color:#ABC1BB;
    padding-right:16px;
    font-size:13px;
    height:30px;
}

#container1 { left:20px;top:50px; }
#container2 { left:250px;top:50px; }
#container3 { left:480px;top:50px; }
#container4 { left:710px;top:50px; }
#container5 { left:600px;top:340px; }
#container6 { left:370px;top:340px; }
#container7 { left:140px;top:340px; }

.del, .node-collapse {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:5px;
    background-color:white;
    padding:1px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:13px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}

.del:after {
    content:"X";
}

.node-collapse {
    right:29px;
    text-align: center;
}

.node-collapse:after {
    content:"-";
}

.group-container.collapsed .node-collapse:after {
    content:"+";
}

.del[delete-all] {
    background-color: pink;
}

.jtk-connector path {
    stroke-width:1;
}

.jtk-group-collapsed .w, .jtk-group-collapsed ul, .jtk-group-collapsed .container, .jtk-group-collapsed .name {
    display:none;
}

.jtk-drag-hover {
    outline:4px solid cornflowerblue;
}

.katavorio-ghost-proxy {
    outline:2px solid red;
}

.events {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    border-left:4px solid #58775d;
    bottom:0;
    width:156px;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding-left:11px;
    background-color: white;
}

#events {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #58775d;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 256px;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding-left: 11px;
    background-color: white;
}

.events h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

The drag drop nodes will get populated in the sides and it will be cloned that logic is done.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the JSplumb documentation on master.. and added the similar code by creating a separate component and css file. Automatically When I dropped the created nodes inside the group it got added to the group. Delete is also working fine but for minimize we need to make the changes based on the class collapsed which gets added to the group div.